# Does PCF Dev show Actuator endpoints and expose log level configuration for Java app?

Tags: spring-boot, logging, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry, spring-boot-actuator

I'm running a demo Spring Boot app with an actuator enabled in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

however the endpoints the actuator is supposed to provide (Health Checks, Traces, etc.) are not showing in the PCF Dev Apps Manager:

[image]

Is that normal behavior and they would be enabled on the public cloud deployment or am I missing something in my configuration?

Similarly, on the Logs tab I don't see a log level configuration control through which setting a log level on a particular Java package is possible.  Is that the regular behavior?  How to configure logging and tracing?

Answer (score 0):

For logging setup , you need to add configurations in applications.properties and it is not available as separate option in the logs window.  For changing your logs at run time, you need to setup a config server/environment variable and use your actuator ends point to refresh it at run time.  Hope this helps.